# How can I get all the objects create by a user in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get all the source code of objects created (not owned) only by users, so I created this query:

```
SELECT s.owner,
       s.name,
       s.TYPE,
       s.line,
       s.text
  FROM sys.dba_source s, sys.dba_users u
 WHERE s.owner = u.username
   AND u.default_tablespace NOT IN ('SYSTEM', 'SYSAUX')
```

But still I'm finding also objects created automaticaly from oracle for example my user has a TRIGGER calle APEX$_WE_ROWS... , that i never created.  APEX should be a SUFIX that Oracle Express put.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know Oracle doesn't keep a creator in the dictionary. But you can use the information from `dba_objects`:

```
SELECT s.owner,
       s.name,
       s.TYPE,
       s.line,
       s.text,
       o.created,
       o.last_ddl_time
  from sys.dba_source s, sys.dba_users u,
       sys.dba_objects o
 where s.owner = u.username   
   and u.default_tablespace not in ('SYSTEM', 'SYSAUX')
   and s.owner = o.owner and s.name = o.object_name and s.type = o.object_type;
```

`created` and `last_ddl_time` may help you to distinguish between system code and user code.

Comment: Thanks for you anwer and suggestion, at least now I know that probabily is not possibile to retrive this information.